# Kaggle - Tweet Sentiment Extraction - What will be length of word or phrase that supports the sentiment

Tags: sentiment-analysis, kaggle, tweets

Kaggle Problem:https://www.kaggle.com/c/tweet-sentiment-extraction

We have to upload the output file with id and ""

```
<id>,"<word or phrase that supports the sentiment>"
```

The question is how the model will be able to choose the length of the phrase like from x word to y word there is strong sentiment.

Can anyone please help ?

Answer (score 1):

The most common way this is done is by having your model predict a start index and an end index (of the sequence of tokens you want to extract).

Poking through the discussion threads, this was the architecture of the winning entry for that competition: https://www.kaggle.com/c/tweet-sentiment-extraction/discussion/159477

Notice in the first section "Heartkilla" they are predicting two things, y-start and y-end. Further down they mention they filter out predictions where y-start is greater than y-end.